# Does SVM training time depend on content of input data?

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

i'm training a SVM (train_auto from opencv) two times.

Both times i use the same parameters:
C=0.01, 100.000 iterations, 32 features and 24550 samples.
But different input samples. The first time i use just my training data and the second time, less training data + some false negativ, but in complete same amount of training data as in the first step.

The first training is finished after about 2 hours. While the second runs endless (more than 10 hours). How is this possible and how can i solve the problem?

Greetings,
Steffi

Edit some code:

```
void SVMtrain(bool retraining) {

    int factor_pos = 5;
    int factor_neg = 10;

    std::string line;
    int N_pos = 2474;
    N_pos *= factor_pos;

    int N_neg = 0;
    std::ifstream myfile2(LIST_NEG);
    while (std::getline(myfile2, line))
        ++N_neg;
    N_neg *= factor_neg;

    Mat points = createFirstSet(N_pos, N_neg, factor_pos, factor_neg);
    Mat labels = createFirstLabels(N_pos, N_neg);

    Mat all_neg;
    if (retraining) {
        Mat hardNegatives = find_hardNegatives();
        hardNegatives.copyTo(points(Rect(0, points.rows - (MAX_HARD_NEG+1), hardNegatives.cols, hardNegatives.rows)));
    }

    // Train with SVM
    CvSVMParams params;
    params.svm_type = CvSVM::C_SVC;
    params.kernel_type = CvSVM::LINEAR;
    params.C = 0.01; //best option according to Dalal and Triggs
    params.term_crit = cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, iterations, 1e-6);


    CvSVM SVM;
    if (retraining) {
        cout << "Training SVM with " << points.rows << " Datapoints... (" << N_pos << ", " << points.rows - N_pos << ") since: " << getTimeFormatted()<< endl;
        SVM.train_auto(points, labels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
        SVM.save(SVM_2_LOCATION);
    }
    else {
        cout << "Training SVM with " << points.rows << " Datapoints... (" << N_pos << ", " << N_neg << ") since: " << getTimeFormatted() << endl;
        SVM.train_auto(points, labels, Mat(), Mat(), params);
        SVM.save(SVM_LOCATION);
    }
    cout << "finished training at " << getTimeFormatted() << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest that you try a **RBF** kernel if you think the data isn't linearly seperable. Also, you could try a combination of flags, eg: iterations + EPS.

Comment: But RBF normally takes longer than linear, doesn't it? But i will try. Thank you for the tipp.

Answer (score 3):

This shouldn't be possible.

But you mentioned, that for the second training you added some false negatives. While I don't know exactly what your data looks like, I'm assuming, that this makes the data not linearly separable. It could be that this breaks your implementation of the SVM. Otherwise I can't help you further

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm using the SVM for pedestrain detection with 64x128 HoG cells. So the first training shouldn't be linear seperable, i guess?